# Telegraphers' equations for lossy transmission line when $R$, $L$, $G$, and $C$ are frequency dependent

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

The telegraphers' equations are commonly written as

$$\frac{{\partial v(z,t)}}{{\partial z}} + R\space i(z,t) + L\frac{{\partial i(z,t)}}{{\partial t}} = 0$$

$$\frac{{\partial i(z,t)}}{{\partial z}} + G\space v(z,t) + C\frac{{\partial v(z,t)}}{{\partial t}} = 0$$

for which a solution may be found in frequency domain from

$$\frac{\partial^2 V(z)}{\partial z^2} = (R + i \space \omega \space L)(G + i \space \omega \space C) V(z) = \gamma^2 V(z)$$

This is all very well, but it is understood that for lossy transmission lines R, L, G and C are, in general, functions of angular frequency, $\omega$, themselves. So that we may write

$$\frac{\partial^2 V(z,\omega)}{\partial z^2} = (R(\omega) + i \space \omega \space L(\omega))(G(\omega) + i \space \omega \space C(\omega)) V(z,\omega) = \gamma^2 V(z,\omega)$$

How should the telegraphers' equations be modified to reflect this?

Comment: If the coefficients are variable, then there needs to be some extra terms like $R'$, $L'$, etc. floating about. What work have you done in applying the same procedure as the constant coefficient case?

Comment: Why do you find it hard to modify the telegraphers' equations when you actually did already easily modify the solution (your last formula)?

Comment: in practice, if the bandwidth is so wide that the material's dispersion has to be taken into account then the telegrapher's equation is unlikely to work by itself, because it will radiate too and some other than the fundamental TEM modes will show up, etc. But as a matter of principle your question is still a good one. You would have to go back and start with $\Phi = \phi(t)$ and $Q=q(t)$ where now $\Phi(t)=\ell(t) \otimes i(t)$ and $q(t)=c(t) \otimes v (t)$ convolutions. The Fourier transform of $\ell$ and $c$ are the frequency components you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @ Kyle
I haven't done any work applying the same procedure as the constant coefficient case. Rather I can across [https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article/23/12/2286/226944/The-inverse-scattering-problem-for-LCRG an article] which set out the telegraphers' equation in this form. Yet it is well known that only the TEM (lossless) case admits a p.u.l L or R that are simple constants (as appear in the telegraphers' equations given in this form, and I'm not sure either that TEM is an appropriate descriptor of a lossy line. It made me think!

Answer (score 0):

Given that

$$\mathcal{L} \left[r(t) \otimes i(t) \right] = R(s) \space \times \space I(s)$$

and

$$\mathcal{L} \left[l(t) \otimes \frac{{d \space i(t)}}{{dt}} \right] = {L}(s) \space \times s \space I(s)$$

where $\mathcal{L} ( \circ )$ is the [Laplace translform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $\circ$, and $\otimes$ is the [Convolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

It follows that we can write the time domain telegraphers' equations for a lossy line as

$$\frac{{\partial \space v(z,t)}}{{\partial z}} + r(t) \otimes i(z,t) + l(t) \otimes \frac{{\partial \space i(z,t)}}{{\partial t}} = 0$$

$$\frac{{\partial \space i(z,t)}}{{\partial z}} + g(t) \otimes v(z,t) + c(t) \otimes \frac{{\partial \space v(z,t)}}{{\partial t}} = 0$$.

For constant R,L,G, and C, with $\delta(t)$ the Diarac delta function, we can put

$$r(t) = R \space \delta(t)$$
$$l(t) = L \space \delta(t)$$
$$g(t) = G \space \delta(t)$$
$$c(t) = C \space \delta(t)$$

as $R \space \delta(t) \otimes i(t) = R \space i(t)$ etc.

In short, the time domain telegraphers' equations for constant coeficient p.u.l paramters is modified to accomodate the frequency dependent paramters case by replacing each coeficient multiplication by a convolution with the time-domain impulse responce corresponding frequency dependent parameter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).